# When using tailwind css where to store custom css classes

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css for the first time. 
I have custom css classed to make spinner and this classes are not related to tailwind.
This is code from my main css file.
My question is is there better way to organize custom css when using tailwind?
Basucally where to write custom css classes when I need them.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.lds-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.lds-ring div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 4px solid #fa6400;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  border-color: #fa6400 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
}
@keyframes lds-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@layer components {
  .btn-primary {
    @apply py-2 font-bold text-white transition duration-200 rounded shadow-lg  hover:shadow-xl disabled:opacity-50;
  },
  .btn-link {
    @apply mb-6 text-sm hover:underline
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add most/all of that to the tailwind config?

Comment: No reason I just don't know where it should go what is good practice/rule.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation, the following interpretation can be made.

When you need to add truly custom CSS rules to a Tailwind project, the easiest approach is to just add the custom CSS to your stylesheet:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.my-custom-style {
  /* ... */
}
```

For more power, you can also use the @layer directive to add styles to Tailwind’s `base`, `components`, and `utilities` layers:

So we get a question **Why does Tailwind group styles into layers**?

The answer is simple:

In CSS, the order of the rules in your stylesheet decides which declaration wins when two selectors have the same specificity:

```
.btn {
  background: blue;
  /* ... */
}

.bg-black {
  background: black;
}
```

Here, both buttons will be black since .bg-black comes after .btn in the CSS:

```
<button class="btn bg-black">...</button>
<button class="bg-black btn">...</button>
```

To manage this, Tailwind organizes the styles it generates into three different “layers” — a concept popularized by ITCSS.

- The base layer is for things like reset rules or default styles applied to plain HTML elements.
- The components layer is for class-based styles that you want to be able to override with utilities.
- The utilities layer is for small, single-purpose classes that should always take precedence over any other styles.

Being explicit about this makes it easier to understand how your styles will interact with each other, and using the @`layer` directive lets you control the final declaration order while still organizing your actual code in whatever way you like.

For more details , please follow the official tailwind documentation [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-css-and-layer).

Hope it helps!